# How to nest SQL functions in sequelize.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize.JS to connect to a MySQL database. I have the following table structure:

```
products
---------------------
id INT
name VARCHAR
price DECIMAL
price_special DECIMAL
```

I'd like to get the lowest `price` (or `special_price`, when available) and the highest `price` (or `special_price` when available). With raw SQL, I can do the following:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(IF(`price_special` > 0, `price_special`, `price`)) AS `min`, 
    MAX(IF(`price_special` > 0, `price_special`, `price`)) as `max` 
FROM 
    `products`
;
```

I also know I can select a column wrapped by an SQL function in Sequelize, this way:

```
product.findOne({
    attributes: [
        [ Sequelize.fn('MIN', Sequelize.col('price')), 'min' ],
        [ Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.col('price')), 'max' ],
    ]
});
```

However, I don't know how to to nest `MIN` and `IF` functions, the way I do with raw SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After posted my question I found an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4519) with a similar problem.

The solution I got is the following:

```
product.findOne({
    attributes: [
        [ Sequelize.fn('MIN', Sequelize.fn('IF',
                Sequelize.literal('`price_special` > 0'),
                Sequelize.col('price_special'),
                Sequelize.col('price'))), 'min' ],
        [ Sequelize.fn('MAX', Sequelize.fn('IF', 
                Sequelize.literal('`price_special` > 0'), 
                Sequelize.col('price_special'), 
                Sequelize.col('price'))), 'max' ],
    ]
});
```

I personally don't like the `Sequelize.literal` call, but it's working and I don't know how to improve it.